# Joining TAbles for count using Codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join

This is my database

```
branch               category_branch
---------------      ---------------
id_branch            id
category_id          public(1/0)
branch_name          category_name
```

This is my simple function on Model

```
function count_branch_all()
{
    return $this->db
            ->count_all_results('branch');
}
```

I want to count data on table branch where public = 1

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You must join the branch table with the cateroty_branch table with the condition:

```
function count_branch_all()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    ->from('branch');
    ->join('category_branch','branch.category_id=category_branch.id', 'left');
    ->where('public',1);
    return = $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```